# Pressing the equals button gives a value (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, calculator

I am just starting to learn Kotlin, making a calculator program. There was a problem: pressing the "equals" button gives the value "null".
Tell me what to pay attention to?
Perhaps there are more errors.
I will be very grateful

```
fun buEqualEvent(view: View) {
    val newNumber = binding.rezStr.text.toString()
    var finalNumber: Double? = null

    when (op) {

        "*" -> {
            finalNumber = oldNumber.toDouble() * newNumber.toDouble()
        }

        "/" -> {
            finalNumber = oldNumber.toDouble() / newNumber.toDouble()
        }

        "+" -> {
            finalNumber = oldNumber.toDouble() + newNumber.toDouble()
        }

        "-" -> {
            finalNumber = oldNumber.toDouble() - newNumber.toDouble()
        }
    }
    binding.rezStr.text = finalNumber.toString()
    isNewOp = true
}
```

Additionally "op" was declared earlier, here's what it looks like

```
var op = "*"
var oldNumber = ""
fun buOpEevent(view: View) {
    val buSelect = view as Button
    when (buSelect.id) {

        binding.btnUmnoz.id -> {
            op = "*"
        }
        binding.btnDel.id -> {
            op = "/ "
        }
        binding.btnMines.id -> {
            op = "-"
        }
        binding.btnPlus.id -> {
            op = "+"
        }

    }
    oldNumber = binding.rezStr.text.toString()
```

Comment: Evidently, if you call this function when `op` doesn't equal one of the four operators in your when statement, it will result in null. It would be more robust to use an Enum for your `op` property instead of a String. Then there is no possibility of there being an unsupported operation in this function.

Comment: question updated
added code "op"

Comment: If one of those branches runs, `toDouble` will crash your app if `oldNumber` doesn't contain a valid number. If it *does* contain a valid number, then `finalNumber` will have a numeric value. So the only possibility is that none of your `when` branches are being called, because `op` doesn't match any of them, like *Tenfour04* says. Try debugging or at least logging the value of `op` before `when` runs, so you can check it. Debugging would be best so you can see exactly what the contents are - for example up there you've written `op = "/ "` which has a rogue space in it, hard to see in a log

Answer (score 0):

This code may be useful for you

```
          binding.MUL.setOnClickListener {
                operation=Operation.MUL
                clear()
            }
            binding.Div.setOnClickListener {
                operation=Operation.DIV
                clear()
            }
            binding.Sum.setOnClickListener{
                operation=Operation.SUM
                clear()
            }
            binding.MIN.setOnClickListener {
                operation=Operation.MIN
                clear()
            }
    
            binding.result.setOnClickListener {
                binding.tvResult.text=buEqualEvent(operation!!)
            }


   enum class Operation{
        MUL,DIV,MIN,SUM
    }


   fun clear(){
        oldNumber = binding.editTextNumber.text.toString().toInt()
        binding.editTextNumber.setText("")
    }
    private var oldNumber=0
    var operation:Operation?=null
    fun buEqualEvent(op: Operation): String {
        val newNumber = binding.editTextNumber.text.toString()

        when (op) {
            Operation.MUL -> {
                return (oldNumber.toDouble() * newNumber.toDouble()).toString()
            }

            Operation.DIV -> {
                return (oldNumber.toDouble() / newNumber.toDouble()).toString()
            }

            Operation.SUM -> {
                return (oldNumber.toDouble() + newNumber.toDouble()).toString()
            }

            Operation.MIN -> {
                return (oldNumber.toDouble() - newNumber.toDouble()).toString()
            }
            else -> {
                return "0"
            }
        }
    }
```